# Does the closure of a strict sublevel set of a continuous function equal a non-strict sublevel set?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, set-valued-analysis

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be closed and $f$ be a continuous real valued function on $X$.

Consider now the sets
\begin{align}
S_{<}   = \{ x \in X : f(x) < 0 \}, &&
S_{\le} = \{ x \in X : f(x) \le 0 \}.
\end{align}

Is it generally true that if $ S_{<} \ne \emptyset$, then $\overline{S_{<}} = S_{\le}$?

Comment: Counterexample: $f \equiv 0$?

Comment: I should have included the assumption that $S_{<}$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is not true as madnessweasley's counterexample shows. If $S_{<}$ is non-empty, a counterexample is given by $f(x) = -1$ for $x \in A \subseteq X$ which is not dense in $X$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in X \setminus A$.

In general the result is true if $f$ is continuous and closed:

Note that $S_{<} := f^{-1}((- \infty, 0))$ and $S_{<} := f^{-1}((- \infty, 0])$ and $\overline{(- \infty, 0)} = (-\infty, 0]$. If $f$ is continuous, we have $f^{-1}(\overline{(- \infty, 0)}) \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(-\infty, 0))} = \overline{S_{<}}$. If in addition $f$ is closed, then this is an equality.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether $\{x \ | \ f(x)=0\}$ is contained in the closure of  $f^{-1}( (-\infty, 0))$. Note that points in the  interior of the zero set cannot be in the closure of $\{x \ \ f(x)\ne 0\}$.  So now we have very simple counterexamples to the statement posted. For instance:
$f(x) =\max (0, |x|-1)$.